# Fork() cannot be called from a Device Driver in Linux

Tags: c, linux, kernel, fork, device-driver

So, I'm writing this driver which receives a "command" via "write" and it is supposed to call fork and let the child finish the job while the parent dies.

When I compile it the output is this.

```
victor@victor-desktop:~/Área de Trabalho/mc504-linux/linux-3.17.2$ make -j 5 ARCH=i386
CHK     include/config/kernel.release
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
CHK     include/generated/compile.h
CC [M]  drivers/ofd/ofcd-lastchar.o
drivers/ofd/ofcd-lastchar.c: In function ‘my_read’:
drivers/ofd/ofcd-lastchar.c:36:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration
 child_pid = fork();
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:263: recipe for target 'drivers/ofd/ofcd-lastchar.o' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/ofd/ofcd-lastchar.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:404: recipe for target 'drivers/ofd' failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/ofd] Error 2
Makefile:929: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

I'm using a Linux downloaded from [here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Eislene/2s2014-mc514/mc504-linux-compilado.tar.xz).

And the driver is this. It only has a fork() call.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

static dev_t first; // Global variable for the first device number
static struct cdev c_dev; // Global variable for the character device structure
static struct class *cl; // Global variable for the device class

static char c;

static int my_open(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
  /*
  Abrir devera alocar um pedaço da memoria e salvar 
  */
  printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: open()\n");
  return 0;
}
static int my_close(struct inode *i, struct file *f)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: close()\n");
  return 0;
}

static ssize_t my_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    child_pid = fork();
    if(child_pid == 0)
      printk(KERN_INFO "child: read()\n");
    else
      printk(KERN_INFO "father: read()\n");
    if (copy_to_user(buf, &c, 1) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;
    else
        return 1;
}
static ssize_t my_write(struct file *f, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: write()\n");
    if (copy_from_user(&c, buf + len - 1, 1) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;
    else
        return len;
};

static struct file_operations pugs_fops =
  {
      .owner = THIS_MODULE,
      .open = my_open,
      .release = my_close,
      .read = my_read,
      .write = my_write
  };

static int __init ofcd_init(void) /* Constructor */
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Namaskar: ofcd-lastchar registered");
  if (alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 1, "ofcd-lastchar") < 0)
    {
      return -1;
    }
  if ((cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "chardrv")) == NULL)
    {
      unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
      return -1;
    }
  if (device_create(cl, NULL, first, NULL, "ofcd-lastchar") == NULL)
    {
      class_destroy(cl);
      unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
      return -1;
    }
  cdev_init(&c_dev, &pugs_fops);
  if (cdev_add(&c_dev, first, 1) == -1)
    {
      device_destroy(cl, first);
      class_destroy(cl);
      unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
      return -1;
    }
  return 0;
}

static void __exit ofcd_exit(void) /* Destructor */
{
  cdev_del(&c_dev);
  device_destroy(cl, first);
  class_destroy(cl);
  unregister_chrdev_region(first, 1);
  printk(KERN_INFO "Alvida: ofcd-lastchar unregistered");
}

module_init(ofcd_init);
module_exit(ofcd_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Anil Kumar Pugalia <email_at_sarika-pugs_dot_com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Our First Character Driver");
```

The big question is: Can `fork();` be called from a Device Driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) inside the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) (because [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are the interface from user-land applications to [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29)), and you really should not start a process inside a [driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver), since with a few painful exceptions (like `/sbin/init` of pid 1, or maybe in some particular cases `/sbin/hotplug` etc...) every process is started by another process calling [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (or perhaps [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) or [vfork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html)...). Your kernel module becomes part of the kernel when loaded (e.g. with [insmod(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/insmod.8.html)...); however, [kernel threads](http://tuxthink.blogspot.fr/2011/02/kernel-thread-creation-1.html) add complexity to the picture.

Maybe you should consider [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).

I recommend learning much more about Linux user-land programming (e.g. read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)) before daring coding some kernel module.

You might read about [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) & [CPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) & [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29). It could suggest you a way of thinking your driver code differently.

Comment: The device is supposed to be educational only. A simple device driver that uses a little of multiprocess.

Comment: Even an educational driver cannot do syscalls.

Comment: No, you cannot use threads neither. You might google for kernel threads.